# Forcing the operation system to perform cleanup after a "subroutine"

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm writing an images-processing program in C++. For this purpose, I have modified a third party program (an edge detector) into a static library that I use in *my* program.

It seams the original edge detector relied on the OS to clean up the memory after the main function has been executed. Unfortunately, after I have modified this original code, the main function became a "common" repeatedly called function and no automatic cleaning is therefore performed. The result is a huge memory leak every time the function is called.

I'm not able to exhaustively review the whole code of the detector to fix this. I'd like therefore to ask: In general, is there a way to separate a "subroutine" of the whole program (in my case the detector) from the rest and to force the OS to clean up after the subroutine as if it was a stand-alone program? Could there be a solution with the use of threads, for example?

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a *nix platform, perhaps you could `fork` the library call.

Answer (score 0):

You could run it in a separate process that would be kicked in from your program.

There are ways to pipe the child-process'es stdin, stdout, so you can control it.

What you could also try is to use valgrind to detect the leaks and fix them.

If you are on linux, you can google for: fork() or system() functions to create a child process.